# d3.js Making the node size proportional to it's degree by using d.weight causing a error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a fully functional force directed graph. Now I am trying to have the node size i.e the radius of the nodes proportional to there degrees.

```
       var node = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(d3GraphData.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r",function(d) {return d.weight * 2;})
```

This causes all the nodes to disappear and I get a error stating

```
     Error: <circle> attribute r: Expected length, "NaN".
```

This is still my first project in d3.js. Is there more complexity involved in making the node radius proportional to the degree.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/pfkcb5qb/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code and the degree information is not included in your nodes:

`group:1
id:"10000000500874"
index:252
type:"Agent"
visible:true
vx:-0.06967413905945731
vy:0.08562878588481856
x:179.01501937845038
y:424.4658956406365`

You will first need to compute the degree, store it as a new property and then change the radius accordingly.

Comment: how do I compute the degree ..I actually tried looking for examples but could not find any thing where the weight or the degree is computed.

Comment: I thought the attribute .weight already has the node degree computed.  and can be accessed as d.weight